# Optimize Generic Method logic

Tags: c#, class, c#-4.0, logic, generic-method

I have one Generic Method, where we can pass a T as a interface type. Method returns a list of data corresponding T type. I have 20-25 same condition for this method how can I optimize logic.

Class implements interface. example Student class implements IStudent interface.

```
public ObservableCollection<T> GetAll<T>()
    {
        try
        {
            if (typeof(T) == typeof(IStudent))
            {                 
                return GetAll<T, Student>();
            }
            else if (typeof(T) == typeof(IZone))
            {
                return GetAll<T, Zone>();
            }
            else if (typeof(T) == typeof(IEmployee))
            {
                return GetAll<T, Employee>();
            }
            else if (typeof(T) == typeof(ICourse))
            {
                return GetAll<T, Course>();
            }
         }
    }
```

Here caller pass interface type T and I check type of T. I pass to other function T and class which will return list of T. Other function in base class which I can not change.
Could anyone suggest me something about same.

Comment: Doesn't this logic completly defy the point of generics in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try and do this through reflection.

```
public ObservableCollection<T> GetAll<T>()
{
    var typeName = typeof(T).FullName;
    var indexOfDot = typeName.LastIndexOf('.');
    var newTypeName = typeName.SubString(0, indexOfDot) + '.' + typeName.SubString(indexOfDot + 1);
    var newType = Type.GetType(newTypeName);
    var methodTypes = new [] { typeof(T), newType };
    var method = GetType().GetMethod("GetAll");
    var typedMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(methodTypes);
    return (ObservableCollection<T>) typedMethod.Invoke(this, new object[0]);
}
```

Not pretty, but should do the job and does is generically.

The only caveat the current way is that the `GetAll` method is overloaded by generic parameters, so it may not get you the right method, or fail because there are two. I'll have a look if the right one can be indicated.

Answer (score 5):

I think you don"t need generic at all, you can create a common interface implemented by all your types :

```
public interface IObservableElement
{
    public ObservableCollection<IObservableElement> GetAll();
}
```

Comment: Here caller pass interface type and I check type of T. I pass to other function T and class which will return list of T. Other function in base class which I can not change.

Comment: If you can't change the design based on generic, reflection as suggested by René Wolferink should be the best issue